# in js, how do i replace add \n (not a new line marker) as a string to end of each line in a textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, replace

ok so ill try to be clear.

I have a textarea and it will have multiple lines of text and at the end of each line i want to add \n but the replace function just adds a new line. I am then going to put the result into a different textarea after the string has been modified.

i have tried a variety of methods but cant seem to get it to work

example of my current stage

```
var my_text=$("textarea[name=text_area]").val();    
my_text=my_text.replace(/\n/g,'["\n"]\n');
my_text=$("textarea[name=modifiedtext_area]")
```

i want the textbox content to go from

```
fgdf
g
sdfg
asdff
```

to the below in the new textarea

```
fgdf\n
g\n
sdfg\n
asdff\n
```

Comment: escape the backslash: "\\".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If want to show the actual text `\n` you have to escape the slash `\\n`

```
my_text=my_text.replace(/\n/g,"\\n\n");
```